# jquery ui autocomplete: remote source problem

Tags: jquery, json, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Im using jQuery UI autocomplete.

When i use a local variable as source it works.

```
var json = [
            {type: "Utente",label: "Luca XXXX",url: "http://lvh.me:3000/users/4dde465add53e04e5c000001"},

            {type: "Domanda",label: "Luca asdas adsfdsfdsf sdsd",url: "http://lvh.me:3000/questions/luca-asdas-adsfdsfdsf-sdsd"},
    ];
```

But when i return the same source from another file, it doesnt work. I find the JSON object in firebug and it seems the same as my local variable json.

The code is the following:

```
$( ".query-input" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: "/search.json",
        select: function( event, ui ) { window.location = ui.item.url }
    })
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a href=" + item.url + ">"+ item.label +"</a><span>" + item.type + "</span>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

This is search.json.erb file:

```
[<% @results.each do |r| %>
<% if r.is_a? User %>
    {type: "Utente",label: <%= r.name.to_json.html_safe %>,url: <%= user_url(r.id).to_json.html_safe %>},
<% elsif r.is_a? Question %>
    {type: "Domanda",label: <%= r.text.to_json.html_safe %>,url: <%= question_url(r.slug).to_json.html_safe %>},
<% elsif r.is_a? Topic %>
    {type: "Argomento",label: <%= r.name.to_json.html_safe %>,url: <%= topic_path(r.id).to_json.html_safe %>},
<% end %>
<% end %>]
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the missed callback. Autocomplete needs a callback param to function properly.
The right search.json code is the following:

```
<%= "#{params[ :callback ]}(" if params[:callback] -%>
[<% @results.each_with_index do |r, i| %>
  <% if r.is_a? User %>
    {
      type: "Utente",
      label: <%= r.name.to_json.html_safe %>,
      url: "<%= user_url(r.id) %>"
    }
  <% elsif r.is_a? Question %>
    {
      type: "Domanda",
      label: <%= r.text.to_json.html_safe %>,
      url: "<%= question_url(r.slug) %>"
    }
  <% elsif r.is_a? Topic %>
    {
      type: "Argomento",
      label: <%= r.name.to_json.html_safe %>,
      url: "<%= topic_path(r.slug) %>"
    }
  <% end %>
  <%= "," unless i == @results.count - 1 %>
<% end %>]
<%= ")" if params[:callback] -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $( ".query-input" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 3,
            dataType: 'json',
            source: "/search.json",
            select: function( event, ui ) { window.location = ui.item.url }
})
```

You should mention dataType as 'json'

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I don't think `html_safe` will wrap the value with double quote characters.</strike>

**EDIT:** Turns out `html_safe` *does* add double quote characters. However, the JSON in your Firebug trace is invalid and does not match the code in your question:

```
[
    {
        type: "Utente",
        label: "Luca XXXX",
        url: "lvh.me:3000/users/4dde465add53e04e5c000001"; <-- syntax error
    }, {
        type: "Domanda",
        label: "Luca asdas adsfdsfdsf sdsd",
        url: "lvh.me:3000/questions/luca-asdas-adsfdsfdsf-sdsd"; <-- syntax error
    },
]
```

There should not be a semicolon character after the value of `url`.

Comment: doen't work. 
html_safe wrap value with double quote. 
This is copy/paste of response from firebug:

[
  {type: "Utente",label: "Luca XXXX",url: "http://lvh.me:3000/users/4dde465add53e04e5c000001"},

  {type: "Domanda",label: "Luca asdas adsfdsfdsf sdsd",url: "http://lvh.me:3000/questions/luca-asdas-adsfdsfdsf-sdsd"},
]